# example of integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \frac {1}{1+x^8}dx=L$ then

$1.L <1$

$2.L> 1$

$3.L <\frac {\pi}{4} $

$4.L >\frac {\pi}{4} $

I tried but I got answer L is less than $\frac {1}{2} $ but I don't the answer. Is right or not.

Here the answers can be multiple means it is possible that more than one option can be answer of this question
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Since there are no limits on the integral, it is an *indefinite* integral, and so it makes no sense to speak of it as having a value.

**EDIT** Now the OP has changed the question to have limits, so the question actually makes sense. The integral is clearly NOT smaller than $1/2,$ since the integrand is always bigger than $1/2.$ But smaller than $1.$ The integrand is also bigger than $1/(1+x^2).$ the last two statements should eliminate all but one possibility.

Comment: Sorry I was editing my question at that time.now you can see the limits.

Comment: Can I compute what is the exact value of integration?

Comment: @SiddhantTrivedi Yes, there is a closed form, but it is a lot more work than needs doing.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the answer of this question?

Comment: @SiddhantTrivedi I have told you enough, now do a little work yourself.

Comment: Integral is approximately 0.9254

Answer (score 1):

Note that $1 + x^8 \ge 1$ so

$$
\frac{1}{1+x^8} \le 1 \Rightarrow \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^8} dx \le \int_0^1 1 dx =1 $$

So 1) is true.

To go other way
$ 2 \ge 1+x^8$ So the integral is $\ge 1/2$. So can't say about (3)

Comment: Why dont you read my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the comment.

Comment: I gave him an essentially complete answer an hour ago, giving both upper and lower bounds, so I am puzzled about why you are wasting your time on this.

Comment: Sorry, your answer did not show up until saw the comment. I need sleep! It is late here and I really should not be doing this.

Comment: That goes for all of us:)

Answer (score 0):

For the lower bound, note that for $ x \in [0, 1], \: 1 + x^8 \le 1 + x^2 $, so:

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^8} \ge \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \arctan x \big|_0^1 = \frac{\pi}{4}$$